# npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic

Tags: meteor, deployment, npm, linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.10

what's the cause of this error, and how do I fix it. I'm trying to install NPM and Nodejs. Please, quick response needed. This is truly pulling my hairs. I never knew it is this hard to deploy a meteor app because of all the dependencies.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/bin/node" "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/bin/npm" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.8.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! path /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/bin/node" "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.8.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install script 'node npm-rebuild.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node npm-rebuild.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
meteor@christdoes:~/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server$ ^C
meteor@christdoes:~/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server$
```

Comment: The file that it's complaining about has a backslash `\\` in the path `node_modules/sshpk/bin\\sshpk-conv` - is that something to do with the problem. Are you developing on Windows and deploying to Linux?

Comment: Yes. Deploying from Windows to linux. I'm still getting the problem.